# How to convert BigInteger to String?

Tags: java, string, arrays, biginteger

I decrypted a data and got a BigInt and when I tried to convert it to string I got some Wired characters.

Code for getting BigInteger

```
BigInteger dec = process.Decrypt(sec);
```

Code for getting ByteArray

```
byte testBy[] = dec.toByteArray();
```

Code for Converting into String

```
String ss = new String(testBy);
System.out.println(ss);
```

and I tried this code too

```
String ss = new String(testBy);
System.out.println(ss, "UTF8");
```

I'm getting this output

```
=^ö½ß‡k+Éæ‚ûŽ3B‚+…Òæ?&¶?kÛUô—c
```

Help me out here..

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/math/biginteger_tostring_radix.htm

Comment: why do you need the byte array? Just use BigInteger.toString() method

Comment: Pretty sure there is no `println(String, String)` method. Also, `String ss = new String(testBy, "UTF-8");` would be acceptable.

Comment: What is `process.Decrypt`? Sure it returns a `BigInteger`, but if it is supposed to hold a `String` we will need more information about how this method actually stores data inside the `BigInteger`. Check its API documentation.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly I'm trying an decryption of an encrypted data here is the code
return c.modPow(lambda, nsquare).subtract(BigInteger.ONE).divide(n).multiply(u).mod(n);

Answer (score 16):

BigInteger has a [`toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#toString%28%29) method, which gives a decimal string representation of the value.

Comment: NOTE : public String toString(int radix) ; else default value of 10

Comment: @DonRoby so how can i convert that bigInt to original text. i mean decrypted text

Comment: Sivashankar, you asked your question wrong. this is clearly a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here. You don't want a `String` representing the number that the `BigInteger` holds. You want the decrypted text. And the answer is, we can't help you without knowing your library (there is a gazillion ways in which the decrypted data can be stored inside the `BigInteger`, plus another gazillion things that the data can really be).

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly let me put in another way when i give a small data file the above code is working properly but if i gave a large data file it's showing that above output. Large  means just a 20kb file.

Comment: We still can't help you Sivas. The point is, you are asking for specific details of a implementation that we know nothing about. It can be a bug, there can be something missing, or it can be designed that way - we don't know. If this is code you own, debug the encryption process; if it is a library, read its documentations. If it is a popular / well known cryptography library ask a new question about "How can I decrypt my file using library XXX" and providing relevant details about how you have encrypted it.

Answer (score 1):

A call to `System.out.println(dec)` should print the decimal representation of `dec` correctly.

So just make sure that `BigInteger dec = process.Decrypt(sec)` yields the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

`toString()` method convert BigInteger to String.Actually it overrides the Object toString() method.Or directly pass BigInteger object to System.out.println() because println bydefault takes Object.toString().